# Event wont fire Custom property, EPiServer

Tags: events, episerver, customproperty

For some reason my button wont fire the click-event..
As for now I only have an asp:button with the runat,OnClick and Id attributes.. I have checked a few times that the name of the event is the same as the value of the OnClick attribute..
It does how ever fire the Page_Load event..

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a postback button in a custom property?

Answer (score 0):

Is your method name `ButtonId_Click` ?

If it's not, make sure you have set `AutoEventWireup="false"` in your page declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load is triggered on each page load/postback. So, it will fire for any submit button.

Can you post your HTML as well as your event handler in code-behind?